# how to set element through Xpath, inside those element which was allready set using Xpath?

Tags: xpath, odoo, odoo-10

I want to direct position of element using xpath inside other element which was already set through xpath.

**Below one is already set through the xpath (which i din't change)**

```
<xpath expr='//div[@id='d']' position='inside'>

  <form id='a'>

      //Base_Code       

  </form>    

</xpath>
```

**Now what i want that, I want to set below element after the above 'form'.**

```
<xpath expr='//div[@id='d']//form[@id='a']' position='after'>

  <div id='b'>

      //My_Code       

  </form>    

</xpath>
```

**Error is : cannot be located in parent view**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try as following by inheriting already inherited view:

```
<xpath expr="//form[@id='a']" position="after">
    <div id='b'>
    </div>
</xpath>
```